# Remove page/ of High Voltage for statics page rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello I am using [High Voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) for my statics pages in rails but I see the next structure when I make my statics pages:

myserver.com/**pages**/about

myserver.com/**pages**/privacy

myserver.com/**pages**/terms
.

.

.

.

I don't want that **"page"** word appear. I want that appear this structure

myserver.com/about

myserver.com/privacy

myserver.com/terms

Thank you very much. Regards!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

see [this bug](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage/issues/12)

this might work:

```
match '/:id' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :as => :static, :via => :get
```

EDIT:

When you use the above instructions, you also need to go through your views and change all instances of:

```
page_path(:id=>:about)
```

to:

```
static_path(:id=>:about)`
```

or better yet, just:

```
static_path(:about)
```

So find all the link_to's in your views and make the changes above... Your urls will no longer have the word **pages** in them

hope this helps

Comment: Dont working :(, I have check this fix for me, but not working fine. My links _footer.html.erb have this structure

<%= link_to "About", page_path(:id => "about") %>
I see yet this structure of my footer link

myserver.com/pages/about,

myserver.com/pages/privacy,

myserver.com/pages/terms

Thank you!

Comment: I will update my answer with more instructions, this does work, I'm using it right now :)

Comment: ok, I updated my answer. Remember to put your route as close to the bottom of routes.rb as you can, that seems to help prevent other problems later on

Comment: Now Yes working fine :D. static_path(:about) working fine. Thank you very much!!

Comment: no problem, remember what i said about putting the route lower down the page, as I found it can conflict with others if you don't

Comment: You wouldn't need to edit the routes if you just simply overwrote the routing helper, defining it like `:as => :page` rather than `:as => :static`. The last route defined will be the one that takes precedence.

Comment: Can you please explain why `static_path(:about)` is better? And what about to use `:` for nested directories, like `static_path(:about/address)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the need for the "/pages" portion of the URL by adding the following to your config/routes.rb file.

```
match '/*id' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :as => :static, :via => :get
```

The "*" will allow support for nested directories.

Then you can create a link "/en/test" pointing to app/views/pages/en/test.html.erb as follows:

```
<%= link_to "Test", static_path("en/test") %>
```

To complete your semi-static setup, you may wish to consider 2 more things.

1) Some basic routes (placed above the previous route line) for default content for directories (as required)

```
root :to => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :id => 'index' # map root to 'index.html'
match '/en' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :id => 'en/test' # map '/en' to '/en/test.html'
```

2) A nice SEO redirection to remove any extra trailing slashes: http://nanceskitchen.com/2010/05/19/seo-heroku-ruby-on-rails-and-removing-those-darn-trailing-slashes/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 match '*id', :to => 'high_voltage/pages#show'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage#top-level-routes) this can now be done by adding the code below to the high_voltage initializer. I have used this successfully in rails 4+ using the 2.4 version of the gem.

```
# config/initializers/high_voltage.rb
HighVoltage.configure do |config|
  config.route_drawer = HighVoltage::RouteDrawers::Root
end
```