# error to customize error 404 rails 3.1 with hight_voltage gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes, http-status-code-404

Hi guys I remove /page from high_voltage gem with this answer.

[Remove page/ of High Voltage for statics page rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518418/remove-page-of-high-voltage-for-statics-page-rails)

I have in my routes for high_voltage this:

```
match '/:id' => 'high_voltage/pages#show', :as => :static, :via => :get
```

For maintenance page 404 in rails 3.1 I follow this fix http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/36-rails-3-0-rescue-from-routing-error-solution with **errors_controller.rb** with the next code:

```
def routing
  render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :status => 404, :layout => false
 end
```

Then I add to **routes.rb** the next code for maintenance page 404 in rails

```
match '*a', :to => 'errors#routing'
```

The problem is that if I put in browser **www.mydomain.com/sdfs** dont working 404 system error and show **No such page: sdfs**

but however if I put www.mydomain.com/a_controller/action/sdfs yes working fine the fix for error 404 page.

I think that problem is my routes.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you kevinthopson for mi this dont working fine :(.

I have in my **routes.rb**:

```
match '/:id' => 'pages#show', :as => :static, :via => :get
```

I have added this in **pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < HighVoltage::PagesController
  rescue_from ActionView::MissingTemplate do |exception|
    render_not_found
  end
end
```

I have added this code to **aplication_controller.rb:**

```
def render_not_found
   render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :status => 404, :layout => false
  end
```

Working fine if you put now:

localhost:3000/**dfadsfadsf**

The problem now is that if you put for example that routes in navigation bar:

localhost:3000/users_or_static_page/**asdfadfadfa**

**Dont working for me :(.**

Comment: The problem was fix upload the line `match `'/:id' => 'pages#show', :as => :static, :via => :get` to the top from routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by extending the HighVoltage::PagesController and modifying the error catching:

```
class PagesController < HighVoltage::PagesController
  rescue_from ActionView::MissingTemplate do |exception|
    render_not_found
  end
end
```

In my case though, my 404 function resides in my application controller so that it can easily be called from any location. If you make the same change, you will also need to update your route:

```
match '/:id' => 'pages#show', :as => :static, :via => :get
```